# monitorDownload doesn't work well with DataExporter

Tags: primefaces

all. I am a student learning PrimeFaces. Downloading will be started after pressing a button. This code shows a message for user during generating a file. I added a pop up message, but it doesn't close after downloading. It seems oncomplete() action doesn't work at all. Please help me this.

```
<p:commandButton onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(showStatus, hideStatus)" value="Export" title="Export" ajax="false" >
    <l:dataExporter source="tblResult" fileType="csv" fileName="reportCSV" fileOptions="#{contextBean.csvExportOptions}" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog header="Report Generation" message="Exporting" widgetVar="repGenerationDlgBtn" modal="true" >
    <p:commandButton value="Ok" type="button" onclick="hideStatusWithLoading();"/>
</p:confirmDialog>

<div id="loading_image">
    <p:graphicImage widgetVar="loading_image" library="images" name="loading.gif"/>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
function showStatus() { repGenerationDlgBtn.show(); }
function hideStatus() { 
    repGenerationDlgBtn.hide(); 
    document.getElementById('loading_image').style.visibility="hidden";
}
function hideStatusWithLoading() {
    repGenerationDlgBtn.hide();
    document.getElementById('loading_image').style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Although you download a file with the dataexporter, it might just be that the integration with 'monitorDownload' is not there like the fileDownkoad has. If you want to be sure, check the source of PF, it is easy to read. Maybe file an enhancement issue after trying the latest PF version

Comment: Thanks for replying this. First, my PF version is 3.5. When I read PF user guide pdf, it said below the following reply. I am going to look inside of source codes with Google.

Comment: DataExport is a non-ajax process so ajaxStatus component cannot apply. See FileDownload Monitor Status section to find out how monitor export process. Same solution applies to data export as well.

Comment: why start with 3.5? And not 6.0?

Comment: There is a team to study this, this team use this version haha. After finishing this team, I am going to study PF lastest version